# c++ SFML keypressed character error

Tags: c++, input, user-input, sfml

I am creating a battleships game where I enter the coordinates in the form A-J x 1-9 for my hit and I am getting these and putting them into a column and row variable and then entering an x in a 2D array at those coordinates.

My issue is that whenever the code enters the event polling loop, for some reason it already thinks I have pressed a key and tells me I have entered a row.

I have attempted to play around with the user input function i have written to debug this with no avail,

NOTE: I am using the keypressed event not the textentered event as i only need the program to recognise 1 key,

here is the relevant code:

```
void GetUserInput()
{
        sf::Event Event; // create an event instance

        std::cout << "waiting for input" << std::endl; // output to console     for debugging purposes

        while(bTurnTaken == false)
        {
            while (menu.pollEvent(Event)) // create a polling loop that     polls the event instance
            {
                if(bRowInputted == false) // if the row has not been entered
                {
                    if(Event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered); // if there is     a TextEntered event ( i.e the user enters the coordinates they would like to hit     for their turn)
                    {
                        if(Event.text.unicode >= 32 && Event.text.unicode <= 126) // if what was entered was a valid character
                        {
                            cRow = static_cast<char>(Event.text.unicode); // take what was entered and store it in the variable iRow
                            ConvertRow(); // calls the function to convert the entered row from A-J format to 0-10
                            std::cout << "Row chosen: " << iRowConverted << std::endl; // output to console for debugging
                            bRowInputted = true; // tells the program the row has been inputted so to move on to getting the column
                        }

                    }
                }

                else if(bRowInputted == true) // if the row has been entered
                {
                    if(Event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered); // if there is a TextEntered event ( i.e the user enters the coordinates they would like to hit for their turn)
                   {
                        if(Event.text.unicode >= 32 && Event.text.unicode <= 126) // if what was entered was a valid character
                        {
                            iColumn = static_cast<char>(Event.text.unicode); // take what was entered and store it in the variable iRow
                            iColumn = iColumn - 49; // converts the ascii value of the pressed character into decimal, also changes the entered 1-10 into 0-9
                            std::cout << "Column chosen: " << iColumn << std::endl; // output to console for debugging
                            bTurnTaken = true; // signal the end of the turn as the program now has desired row and column
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us where exactly the problem is. How do you know "it already thinks I have pressed a key" in what way does this manifest? Additionally are you initializing all the variables correctly (especially the booleans)?

Answer (score 0):

Semi-colon after if(Event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) thus effectively skipping that if statement.
Therefore Event.text.unicode contains an unrelated value which, in some cases, triggers the following if statement.